# Trying to identify these LEGO pieces

Tags: set-identification

Does anyone know what set(s) these belong to? I have been searching but have had no luck. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Both the top build and the bottom left build are not LEGO, but from a clone manufacturer.

Comment: Really? I just checked and the bricks and they do not say lego on the dots. Thank you very much for pointing that out to me. I was very confused as to why I couldn't identify the set. Lego 101.

Answer (score 3):

The back part of this set is from set [7693 ETX Alien Strike](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7693-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) from the Mars Mission theme from 2007. I found this by looking for sets that had at least 4 of the “Plate 1x2 with bar - free ends” in Orange, and then looked at all the matching sets to find the “flag” piece with the (in your case) badly placed sticker.

[image]

The front slope with the circled 4 is not from that set; in fact, I cannot find any such piece on BrickLink at all, so this might be from a clone set as were the other items you originally posted in your question but since removed. Does it have LEGO markings anywhere on the piece?

Comment: Thank you again. I found a box of broken legos when clearing the attic. This was built like this so I just assumed that it fell off as is. I took it apart now and the "4" does not have lego on the dots.  I know my nephew had purchased a bag of pieces at a flea market years ago. He may have built this, and now I figured it was a broken set. Thank you for your time!